# How To Increase Elasticsearch 5.6.7 Write Performance

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I am trying to benchmark my Hot-Warm Structured Elasticsearch cluster.I did a lot tests. I followed many things. I think, my index rate still is not acceptable.

In my cluster, I have 13 hot servers which have SSD, 3 of them has NVMe. Relatively good CPUs. And 3 warm servers. In my test, I get max 250k primary shard ingest, 500k total shards. Since I use 1 replicaton count.

For me It means, 38k document insert for per server, Since I use 1 replica count, it means 19k document per server. For such a basic key value model, the index rate is too slow for me. When I see that I cannot benchmark my real model.

Is there any advice for me?

I did following advices

- bootstrap.memory_lock: true
- thread_pool.bulk.queue_size: 100000 ( at the beginning it was 200, Then I tested 20000. now 100000)
- thread_pool.index.queue_size: 100000 ( at the beginning it was 200)
- Basic key value model. 1 replica, increased refresh interval, high or low shard count. Disabled _source and _all fields. My model is below. Auto generated ids.
- I ingest data using bulk processor. I tested changing document count and concurrency in the client side. I used multiple powerful servers to ingest data. My clients has hot server ips to ingest data, not warm servers.

  {
      "template": "test01*",
      "settings": {
        "index": {
          "routing": {
            "allocation": {
              "require": {
                "box_type": "hot"
              }
            }
          },
          "refresh_interval": "600s",
          "number_of_shards": "26",
          "number_of_replicas": "1"
        }
      },
      "mappings": {
        "test01": {
          "_source": {
            "enabled": false
          },
          "_all": {
            "enabled": false
          }, 
          "dynamic": false,
          "properties": {
            "rt": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "con": {
              "type": "float"
            }
          }
        }
      }
  }

Answer (score 0):

a little advice, index setting should add `index.routing.allocation.total_shards_per_node` to control your index shards evenly distributed across nodes.